# Setting multiple objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am struggling to find a shorthand version of the code shown below. Basically I am saving Events into core data. Each event has up to 15 contacts. newEvent is from an Event class.

The code below works great, but I don't want to have it duplicated 15 times for each contact. Is there an easier way?

```
if ([[selectedContacts objectAtIndex:14] objectAtIndex:0] != (id)[NSNull null]) {
    newEvent.contact15 = [[selectedContacts objectAtIndex:14] objectAtIndex:0];
}
else {
    newEvent.contact15 = @"";
}
```

Comment: Short answer: declare the `contactX` fields to be a single array and loop through it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this code

```
-(void) Solve{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 15 ; i++){
        Contact *con = [newEvent.contacts objectAtIndex:14 - i];
        if ([[selectedContacts objectAtIndex:14 - i] objectAtIndex:0] != (id)[NSNull null]) {
            con = [[selectedContacts objectAtIndex:14 - i] objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        else {
            con = @"";
        }
    }
}
```

just you should define `contact` in your `newEvent` class as `Array`

Comment: I am not sure how to save an array in core data. But this answer looks great, cheers for the help though :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NSSelectorFromString` to translate `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"setContact%d", 15]` to `SEL` value and then using `performSelector`. But ARC won't like that.

You can `#define` a C macro with this statement, then call it 15 times and immediately `#undef` it. It will be much shorter, though not pretty.

But the best would be to redesign the class to have single `contacts` array.